# How to access action-server 5055? (RASA chatbot)

Tags: chatbot, rasa-core

Rasa Core version:0.11.1

Python version: 3.6.2

Operating system (windows, osx, ...): macOS Mojave 10.14

Issue:
Hi
I am new to RASA. And after all the installation when I was making the action-server I met this

`(ChatbotNeptune) Admins-MacBook-Pro:starter-pack-rasa-stack admin$ make action-server
python -m rasa_core_sdk.endpoint --actions actions
INFO:__main__:Starting action endpoint server...
INFO:rasa_core_sdk.executor:Registered function for 'action_joke'.
INFO:__main__:Action endpoint is up and running. on ('0.0.0.0', 5055)`

I don't know where is my action server, I try to access with http://0.0.0.0:5000/ but got "This site can't be reached

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: I guess it was just the wrong port, 5000 instead of 5055, but can you add your solution in case somebody else makes the same mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Use either this

```
http://0.0.0.0:5055/
```

Or this

```
http://localhost:5055
```

Since it is an action server, it doesn't have a graphical user interface.